# Cant post to Azure storage? Invalid Path error

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, multipartform-data

I am trying to add an image I am receiving like this.

```cs
[FunctionName("Imageupload")]
public static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<HttpResponseMessage> RunAsync([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = "HttpTriggerCSharp/name/{name}")]HttpRequestMessage req, string name, TraceWriter log)
{
    //Check if the request contains multipart/form-data.
    if (!req.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
    {
        return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
    }

    var storageConnectionString = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

    var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageConnectionString);
        log.Info(storageConnectionString);
    var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

    // Retrieve a reference to a container.
    CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("temporary-images");

    // Create the container if it doesn't already exist.
    container.CreateIfNotExists();

    //Retrieve reference to a blob named "myblob".
    CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("images");

    try
    {
        string root = blockBlob.Uri.AbsoluteUri;
        var provider2 = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root);
        await req.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);
    }
    catch (StorageException e)
    {
        return req.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound,e.Message);
    }
}
```

The path I am using is right as I checked it and it points to the storage container.

How Can I send the images I receive to Azure storage?

I recieve the error that the path's format is not supported.

My path looks like this : "https://XXXXXXXXXXX.blob.core.windows.net/temporary-images/images"

Comment: Do you get any error message?

Comment: I get given path's format is not supported error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I recieve the error that the path's format is not supported.

As `MultipartFormDataStreamProvider` requests local file path as parameter, so blob address http/https is not valid.

If you want to upload mutiple files to Azure storage container, please have try to use `req.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync();` and `blockBlob.UploadFromStream(stream);` to upload file to azure storage blob. I do a demo, it works correctly on my side.

```
 if (!req.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
 {
     return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
 }
 var storageConnectionString = "connection string";
 var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageConnectionString);
 log.Info(storageConnectionString);
 var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
 CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("temporary-images");
 container.CreateIfNotExists();
 try
 {
    var filesReadToProvider = await req.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync();
    foreach (var stream in filesReadToProvider.Contents)
    {
       var blobName = stream.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName.Trim('"');
       CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);          
       blockBlob.UploadFromStream(stream.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result);

    }

 }
 catch (StorageException e)
 {
        return req.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, e.Message);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `await req.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);` has `provider` passed in, but the line above indicates `provider2` is the variable. Is it possible you've accidentally got `provider` defined elsewhere and it's invalid? Usually when I've got a something2, it indicates I'm trying to get something to work and am fearful of losing the initial idea.

If you instead passed in `provider2`, does it also fail?